# About mutation parameter

Tags: javascript

```
export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState,
  // The `reducers` field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
      // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
      // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
      // immutable state based off those changes
      state.value += 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    // Use the PayloadAction type to declare the contents of `action.payload`
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
  // The `extraReducers` field lets the slice handle actions defined elsewhere,
  // including actions generated by createAsyncThunk or in other slices.
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(incrementAsync.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(incrementAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
        state.value += action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(incrementAsync.rejected, (state) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
      });
  },
});
```

// use it

```
dispatch(incrementAsync(incrementValue))}
```

// we only pass one paramater-incrementValue, why and whay incrementValue stand for, state or action?

We have two parameter in "incrementByAmount" but when we use it we only pass 1 parameter. Please tell me why and what's this parameter stand for, state, action?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you mind clarifying what you are trying to achieve and what the code does currently?

Comment: Welcome, For better result here I recommend to start by expanding on the summary you put in the title and Don't just skip straight to the code